# Grid Floor Axis Not Aligned With Zero?

Tags: transforms, vertices, coordinates

I am having a problem with a vertex that I move to 0 along the x axis, but it is not appearing to be on the axis like it should.

See the screenshot below. I am in top view, and the selected vertex is clearly set to 0 in the in the transform tab. However, it appears at all angles to be to the left of the grid floor which it should be on top of.

[image: Blender Axis Image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the *Local* button selected, which means it starts the coordinate system at the object origin, not the world center. 
Set it to *Global* and it will work like you want, where 0 is at the grid floor.
[image: transform]