# Weird issue with faces

Tags: vertices, faces

When I try creating a new face at a certain place, it seems to be back to front or something for some reason. When I bevel the edge the vertices are also in the wrong places.

Here's a few images to show what I mean:

Before I add the new face:
[image: No Face]

When I add the face:
[image: Face Added]

When I add another face adjacent:
[image: Another Face]

When I try to bevel:
[image]

Comment: i think flip normals will help you out. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29132/how-do-i-flip-normals-on-this-model

Comment: @user2038206 You were right. Thank you :)