# How to precisely set position in edit mode by typing in numbers?

Tags: interface, edit-mode

In Object Mode, I can type in xyz coordinates using this menu:

[image: object menu]

What is the equivalent in Edit Mode, so I can precisely position the parts of an object?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-to-model-effectively-using-exact-measurements. I'd say it's better to use **Transform** scroll in the `N` panel on the right of 3D View because it allows entering values for Object mode when in Object mode and for Edit mode respectively.

Comment: This answer is also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21182/2217

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both in Object Mode and in Edit Mode, you can use the *Transform* menu of the *Properties Panel* on the right-hand side of the 3D View (shortcut <kbd>N</kbd>).

If you have only one vertex selected, it will position that vertex precisely. If you have more than one selected, it will affect the median position of all the selected vertices.

**Edit Mode:**

[image]

**Object Mode:**

[image]